# I want to change App bar height with the key value of JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a use case where I need to change the app bar height with a key value of JSON.

I have this Scaffold which shows a plain appbar and the height of the appbar which is 50px:

```
# app_base.dart

class AppBaseStack extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppBaseStack({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppBaseStackState createState() => _AppBaseStackState();
}

class _AppBaseStackState extends State<AppBaseStack> {
  
double? heightAppBar;
 
 @override
  initState() {
    loadAppbarHeight();
    debugPrint(heightAppBar.toString());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(heightAppBar),
        child: AppBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
loadAppbarHeight() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('[route]/file.json');
    final data = json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      heightAppBar = double.parse(data["app_bar"]["app_bar_height"]);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the JSON file which I want to grab the key value of `app_bar_height` to change the height of the appbar:

```
#app_style.json

{
  "app_bar":
  {
    "app_bar_height": "50"
  }
  
}
```

I want to grab the JSON and then grab key `app_bar_height` and read the value of this key. Then I want to change the height of the app bar with this key value. And if I want to change the app bar height I want to do so by changing the key value of `app_bar_height` from 50 to for example 60 in the JSON file itself.

I don't know how I can do this I tried many things but I want to know if there is an acceptable way in flutter/dart.

**EDIT**

So i made some changes in the `app_base.dart` file. I added the method which loads the json and grabs the json and grabs the key `app_bar_height`. I also added a `initState` which initializes the method but i get an error: `Null check operator used on a null value`

for some reason `heightAppBar` is `null` how can i fix this?

Comment: make a model using this json and then populate it using http package. after that just update your app bar height from the json valu on initstate before widget build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `initState` (before the view is loaded) call a method that does this:

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('[route]/file.json');
final data = json.decode(response);
setState(() {
  heightAppBar = double.parse(data["app_bar"]["app_bar_height"]);
});
```

The method is async, so you need to set a default value to `heightAppBar` and then update.

Comment: I updated my question and added the method you mentioned but i get another error `Null check operator used on a null value` for `heighAppBar`.

Comment: Like i said on the answer, you need to set a default value because the method for read the json is async like (`double heightAppBar = kToolbarHeight;`) or use another widget instead of appbar when `heightAppBar` is null.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use in my project. you can pass height parameter while adding your project.

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final List<Widget>? actions;
  final String? text;
  final TabBar? bottom;
  final Widget? title;
  final bool? disableLeading;
  final Function? leadingAction;


  CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.actions,
    this.disableLeading,
     this.text,
    this.title,
    this.bottom,
    this.leadingAction,
  })  : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(bottom != null ? 120 : 60),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      elevation: 0,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      centerTitle: Platform.isIOS ? true : false,
      title: this.title??AutoSizeText(text??"",
          minFontSize: 11,
          maxFontSize: 18,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
      leading: disableLeading!=null?Container():SizedBox(
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.chevronLeft,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                
                Get.back();
                if(leadingAction!= null)
                leadingAction!();
              })),
      actions: this.actions,
      bottom: this.bottom,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size preferredSize;
}
```